# How to replace elements in list with random number

Tags: python, list

Firstly, I'm a python beginner and just stuck at simple thing.

I want to replace some of my elements in a list with randomly created numbers (by index), according to my values in another list.

Expected output will be like:  [3,2,2,1,3]

My code at below totally doesn't work in the way it should.

```
ori = [4,1,2,1,3]   # some elements inside need to be changed 
num_list = [2,1,1,1]    # numbers that represent index in ori

import random
for num in range(len(num_list)):
    ori[num-1]= random.randint(1,4)
    # I want to replace element with previous one from given index                                                                           
print(ori)
```

Comment: Why the `range(len(` if `num_list` is already the indices to modify? Probably you should not allow duplicate indices in `num_list` as well (e.g. use a `set` instead of a `list`)

Comment: Why index 1 is mentioned 3 times? How can you have expectations about the output of you use random?

Comment: Erm...I mean to go through every item in `num_list` to get the values for modifying

Comment: I think you mean ‘for num in num_list:’

Comment: The value 1 is duplicated, and it should take only one of them for modifying. The expected output I give is just an example, just to mention that I want [0] and [1] value to be changed

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you want to do but it seems to be good with this code. Why num_list contain number "1" 3 times ? In this code it will replace ori[1] by a random number 3 times... Ok for ori[2] will be randomized one time.

```
ori = [4,1,2,1,3]   # some elements inside need to be changed 
num_list = [2,1,1,1]    # numbers that represent index in ori

import random
for num in num_list:
    ori[num]= random.randint(1,4)
print(ori)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that the `num` variable you declare is just the position in `num_list`, so here you will change `ori` at positions `0, 1, 2, 3` (which is what will be represented by your `range`).

You would fix your code like this:

```
ori = [4,1,2,1,3]   # some elements inside need to be changed 
num_list = [2,1,1,1]    # numbers that represent index in ori

import random
for num in num_list:
    ori[num-1]= random.randint(1,4)
```